# My target is dynamically linked against libraries from brew. How to bundle for distribution?

Tags: macos, dynamic-linking, dylib, dyld, install-name-tool

I built an audio plugin. I target `.app` and `.component`.

I dynamically link against a brew-installed library, `libfluidsynth`.

I copied `libfluidsynth` into the `.app` / `.component`.
I used `install_name_tool` to re-link the binary to point to the bundled `libfluidsynth`.

`libfluidsynth` depends on `glib`, `gthread`, `intl`.
I copied those libraries into the bundle, re-linked `libfluidsynth` to prefer the bundled copy.
I also did the same for those libraries and their dependencies.

Here's a quick peek at what that looks like:

```
ls /Users/me/git/juicysfplugin/Builds/MacOSX/build/Release/juicysfplugin.app/Contents/Frameworks
    libfluidsynth.1.7.1.dylib
    libglib-2.0.0.dylib
    libgthread-2.0.0.dylib
    libintl.8.dylib
    libpcre.1.dylib

otool -L \
/Users/me/git/juicysfplugin/Builds/MacOSX/build/Release/juicysfplugin.app/Contents/MacOS/juicysfplugin \
/Users/me/git/juicysfplugin/Builds/MacOSX/build/Release/juicysfplugin.app/Contents/Frameworks/* \
| grep -vE '\t(/System/Library|/usr/lib)'

/Users/me/git/juicysfplugin/Builds/MacOSX/build/Release/juicysfplugin.app/Contents/MacOS/juicysfplugin:
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/libfluidsynth.1.7.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.7.1)
/Users/me/git/juicysfplugin/Builds/MacOSX/build/Release/juicysfplugin.app/Contents/Frameworks/libfluidsynth.1.7.1.dylib:
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libfluidsynth.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.7.1)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5401.0.0, current version 5401.3.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libglib-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5401.0.0, current version 5401.3.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.5.0)
/Users/me/git/juicysfplugin/Builds/MacOSX/build/Release/juicysfplugin.app/Contents/Frameworks/libglib-2.0.0.dylib:
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libglib-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5401.0.0, current version 5401.3.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libpcre.1.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.9.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.5.0)
/Users/me/git/juicysfplugin/Builds/MacOSX/build/Release/juicysfplugin.app/Contents/Frameworks/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib:
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5401.0.0, current version 5401.3.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libglib-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5401.0.0, current version 5401.3.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libpcre.1.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.9.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.5.0)
/Users/me/git/juicysfplugin/Builds/MacOSX/build/Release/juicysfplugin.app/Contents/Frameworks/libintl.8.dylib:
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.5.0)
/Users/me/git/juicysfplugin/Builds/MacOSX/build/Release/juicysfplugin.app/Contents/Frameworks/libpcre.1.dylib:
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libpcre.1.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.9.0)
```

**This worked perfectly for `.app`**. Here, look at the file opens (`opensnoop | grep 'dylib'`):

```
EXECNAME      PATH
juicysfplugin  juicysfplugin.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libfluidsynth.1.7.1.dylib
juicysfplugin  juicysfplugin.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/../Frameworks/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib
juicysfplugin  juicysfplugin.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/../Frameworks/libglib-2.0.0.dylib
juicysfplugin  juicysfplugin.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/../Frameworks/libintl.8.dylib
juicysfplugin  juicysfplugin.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/../Frameworks/../Frameworks/libpcre.1.dylib
```

The `.app` only looks for dylibs inside its bundled Frameworks folder. Perfect.

Then I did the same copies and re-links upon my `.component` target. **This did not work.**

I load the `.component` into an audio plugin host, and check the file opens:

```
EXECNAME     PATH
Plugin Host  /Users/me/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/juicysfplugin.component/Contents/MacOS/juicysfplugin
Plugin Host  /usr/local/lib/libfluidsynth.1.7.1.dylib
Plugin Host  /usr/local/opt/glib/lib/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib
Plugin Host  /usr/local/opt/glib/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib
Plugin Host  /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
Plugin Host  /usr/local/opt/pcre/lib/libpcre.1.dylib
```

It's looking for libraries under `/usr/local`. Why? As a sanity-check, I used `otool` to confirm that I had indeed linked correctly:

```
otool -L \
/Users/me/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/juicysfplugin.component/Contents/MacOS/juicysfplugin \
/Users/me/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/juicysfplugin.component/Contents/Frameworks/* \
| grep -vE '\t(/System/Library|/usr/lib)'

/Users/me/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/juicysfplugin.component/Contents/MacOS/juicysfplugin:
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/libfluidsynth.1.7.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.7.1)
/Users/me/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/juicysfplugin.component/Contents/Frameworks/libfluidsynth.1.7.1.dylib:
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libfluidsynth.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.7.1)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5401.0.0, current version 5401.3.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libglib-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5401.0.0, current version 5401.3.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.5.0)
/Users/me/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/juicysfplugin.component/Contents/Frameworks/libglib-2.0.0.dylib:
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libglib-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5401.0.0, current version 5401.3.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libpcre.1.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.9.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.5.0)
/Users/me/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/juicysfplugin.component/Contents/Frameworks/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib:
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5401.0.0, current version 5401.3.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libglib-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 5401.0.0, current version 5401.3.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libpcre.1.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.9.0)
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.5.0)
/Users/me/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/juicysfplugin.component/Contents/Frameworks/libintl.8.dylib:
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libintl.8.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.5.0)
/Users/me/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components/juicysfplugin.component/Contents/Frameworks/libpcre.1.dylib:
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/libpcre.1.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.9.0)
```

I thought I linked it correctly. I used exactly the same script (it's automated and parameterised). **What am I doing wrong? How did the audio plugin host know to lookup dependencies under `/usr/local`? Why were my library links ignored?**

I've released the binaries to: https://github.com/Birch-san/juicysfplugin/releases/tag/1.0.1

My relinking script is here: https://github.com/Birch-san/juicysfplugin/blob/master/Builds/MacOSX/relink-build-for-distribution.sh

The main difference between how the `.app` and `.component` targets are used is:

- `.app` is standalone
- `.component` is an Audio Unit plugin, that you load into a DAW / audio plugin host.

So, perhaps the runtime dependency resolution is different when a parent process is responsible for loading our executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I [got it working](https://github.com/Birch-san/juicysfplugin/releases/tag/1.0.2).

macOS load-time linking is documented at [`man dyld`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html).

**The problem is that I told my binary to look for libraries relative to `@executable_path`.**

This works fine for .app, because the .app's binary **is** the executable.

But for my .vst and .component plugins, the binary is loaded into a different executable: the audio plugin host.

So, if we want to lookup a library relative to our *binary* (`juicysfplugin.component/Contents/MacOS/juicysfplugin`), **we need to use `@loader_path`, not `@executable_path`.**

---

Now, onto the other mysteries… why did the load-time linker ignore my install path (`@executable_path/../Frameworks/libfluidsynth.1.7.1.dylib`), and instead look for find fluidsynth under `/usr/local/lib/libfluidsynth.1.7.1.dylib`?

It's because of `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`!

> It is used as the default location for libraries not found in their install path.  By default, it is set to `$(HOME)/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib`.

I believe that it **failed** to find the library in the install path. It then looked for that leaf file name — `libfluidsynth.1.7.1.dylib` — under a few directories, including `/usr/local/lib` (which succeded).

Why didn't I see the failed file lookups in opensnoop? Probably it uses a different syscall than `open`/`open_nocancel`/`open_extended`. For example, running `stat` on a file does not show up in opensnoop.

It's also possible that the load-time linking is done by a `dyld` process. SIP would disallow attaching DTrace to this process.